# MATLAB: How to make a property whose name is same as a keyword?

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

In this article (https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/07/16/who-what-why-but-not-this/) near the bottom Loren says that class properties can be the same as keywords. However, how is this possible? If you write a classdef script any attempt to use a keyword (including class keywords like "events") in the properties block gets a red syntax error. Was she mistaken? I'm asking because I really want a property name to be a keyword for a particular application.

Comment: I think that relates to being able to do `obj.if = 0`. But yes, you can't add `if` to the `properties` block.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible by the use of [dynamic properties](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/dynamic-properties-adding-properties-to-an-instance.html), for example:

```
classdef test < dynamicprops
  methods
    function obj = test()
    end
  end
end

var = test();
var.addprop ( 'events' );
var.events = 123;
```

It can make code harder to maintain and its a bit overkill if you only want to name a single property the same as a keyword, in that instance why dont you do something like capitilizing the var name, or prepending it with something - so it still reads like what you want but it doesn't cause the name clash:

```
classdef test
  properties
    Events
    myIf
    % etc...
  end
  methods
    function obj = test()
    end
  end

end
```